# Any alternate method for data sending other than UDP port or TCP/IP port

Tags: php, tcp, udp

Could you please suggest a alternative method for transmitting data over internet by a GSM device to a web server other than via UDP port or TCP port?

Comment: Looks like you should do some research first so that you know *what* you're talking about. An image: [TCP/IP Stack](http://images.yourdictionary.com/tcp-ip)

Comment: got the point..sorry about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Web server" implies that it uses TCP. You cannot speak to a web server with other protocols since it will no longer be a "web server", but rather some other type of server that uses HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

No, using TCP or UDP is the only feasible method.